# java spring boot passing data to frontend

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

we have homework that i am struggling with. What i want to do first is to pass data to frontend.
This is my project structure.
[image]

I want to print all users to frontend.

UserService

```
@Service
    public class UserService {
        private final Map<Long, User> users;

        public UserService(Map<Long, User> users) {
            this.users = users;
        }

        public Map<Long, User> findAllUsers() {
            return users;
        }
    }
```

UserController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")

public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String all(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAllUsers() );
        return "user/all";
    }
}
```

And main that runs the application and where I am creating two users

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class MvcListApplication implements CommandLineRunner {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Engine company = new Engine();
        User user;
        User employee;
        user = company.createUser("fsdfsd","fsdfsd",49484894,"gfdgfdg@fdgfd.com",918191,"fsdfsd","Ulica",456);
        employee = company.createUser("fsdfsd","fsdfsd",494894,"gfdgfdg@fdgfd.com",918191,"fyrtytr","Ulica",456);

        SpringApplication.run(MvcListApplication.class, args);
        log.info("Open in browser: http://localhost:8080");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }


}
```

User class

```
    public class User {

        private String ID;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int idNumber;
        private String email;
        private Address officialAddress;
        private Address postAddress;
        private List<String> contracts = new ArrayList<>();


        public User(String firstName, String lastName, int idNumber, String email, Address officialAddress, Address postAddress) {
            ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setIdNumber(idNumber);
            setEmail(email);
            setOfficialAddress(officialAddress);
            setPostAddress(postAddress);
        }

getters/setters
```

And my frontend templates/user/all

```
<tr th:each="user: ${users}">
    <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
</tr>
```

I am just trying to glue some things together to make it work but it just won't work. 
It runs but i cant see any results no users only hardcoded html on url /users. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users` is of type `Map`. To display all users use `values` method of `Map`.

```html
<tr th:each="user: ${users.values()}">
    <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It does not work. But i found that in UserService is error red highlight with message 'could not autowire. no beans of user or <String, User> types found' when i hover over users in public UserService(Map<String, User> users). Maybe there can be some problem.

Comment: I just needed to create new user correct way in main but this was a problem too so thanks :) accepted